# AJAX Success/Error functions are not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the button that calls the AJAX

```
 <form asp-action="EditItem">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
     ..............
                   <!--<input type="text" class="text-danger float-right" style="border:none;font-size: smaller" id="@("errorMessage")"" readonly /> -->
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="OrderQuantity" id="txt" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OrderQuantity" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="orderId" name="orderId" value="@Model.OrderId" />
        <input type="hidden" id="inventoryorderId" name="inventoryorderId" value="@Model.InventoryOrderId" />
        <input type="hidden" id="inventoryId" name="inventoryId" value="@Model.InventoryId" />
        <button id="button">Update</button>
    </form>
   </div>
 </div>

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var orderedQuantity = $("#txt").val();
        var orderId = $("#orderId").val();
        var inventoryorderId = $("#inventoryorderId").val();
        var inventoryId = $("#inventoryId").val();
        var data = {
            orderId: orderId,
            inventoryorderId: inventoryorderId,
            inventoryId: inventoryId,
            orderedQuantity: orderedQuantity,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "Orders")',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                window.location.href = url + "?custEmail=xyz@rrr.org";               
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

I can see all the parameters are passed to the controller action and dont see any issue in the controllers

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> EditItem(int? orderId, int? inventoryorderId, int? inventoryId, int? orderedQuantity)
    {
        var inventoryOrder = await _context.InventoryOrders
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(io => io.InventoryOrderId == inventoryorderId);
        int curentOrdQuantity = inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity;

        var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(inventoryId);
        int availQty = intData.QuantityAvailable;
        if ((int)orderedQuantity > curentOrdQuantity)
        {
            if (availQty < ((int)orderedQuantity - curentOrdQuantity))
            {
                inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity = curentOrdQuantity;
                _context.Update(inventoryOrder);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Json(new { status = "NotAvailable", available = intData.QuantityAvailable });
            }
            else
            {
                //Updating the Order
                inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity = (int)orderedQuantity;
                _context.Update(inventoryOrder);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                //Updating Inventory
                intData.QuantityAvailable = intData.QuantityAvailable - ((int)orderedQuantity - curentOrdQuantity);
                _context.Update(intData);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Json("");
            }
        }           
        return Json("");
    }
```

I dont see any error in the controller(all updates in the controller are happening without any issues) but the success/error function is not getting executed. I dont see any of the alert() firing both either in success or error. I tried to change from the JsonResult to ActionResult even that doesnt work. Can anyone say what is that I am missing here.

```
public class Order
{
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId  { get; set; }
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
    public int InventoryOrderId { get; set; }
    public string StrainId { get; set; }
    public string StrainName { get; set; }
    public string StrainCode { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Genotype { get; set; }
    public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }
    public int OrderQuantity { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Since your `Json("")` is empty so you shouldn't get any alert.

Comment: But the `var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                window.location.href = url + "?custEmail=xyz@rrr.org";   ` within the success()  is not happeneing

Comment: Additionally, could you also share your `@Model` and `EditItem` controller action so that it can be reproduce.

Comment: `EditItem` controller action/method which I already posted above. Also added my model class

Comment: Okay, try the solution, Hope it would resolve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are returning  return `Json("");` so you can get rid of  `success: function (result)` and replace to  `success: function ()`. Now it will fire `alert` and your `URL redirection` will work.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "Orders")',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Updated Called");
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                window.location.href = url + "?custEmail=xyz@rrr.org";
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Note:***
But if you want to keep check the result then you could follow like below:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "UserLog")',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

            if (result.status === "NotAvailable") {
                alert("NotAvailable");
            }
            else {
                  var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                window.location.href = url + "?custEmail=xyz@rrr.org";
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. But if I am returning custom JSON like `return Json(new { status = "NotAvailable", available = intData.QuantityAvailable });` I need to use this response on form to show the validation error. How can I access the returned JSON

Comment: Yes now checked the update you can set your logic inside the success function as per your requirement. Hope it would help.

Comment: I am running in to another issue, can I ask here or should I create a seperate question

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have created the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69819791/show-the-validation-error-from-the-ajax-calls-inline-on-the-field I am a first time web app developer sorry if I am asking blunt questions.. Thanks again

Comment: Already answered your question.