# Show the validation error from the AJAX calls inline on the field

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-validators

I am trying to show the error message on the field (inline) when the validation fails returned from the AJAX call.

```
        <input type="text" class="text-danger float-right" style="border:none;font-size: smaller" id="@("errorMessage")" readonly />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="OrderQuantity" id="txt" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OrderQuantity" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="orderId" name="orderId" value="@Model.OrderId" />
        <button id="button">Click Me</button>
    </form>
 </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function () {
    var orderedQuantity = $("#txt").val();
    var orderId = $("#orderId").val();
    var data = {
        orderId: orderId,
        orderedQuantity: orderedQuantity
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "Orders")',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.status === "NotAvailable") {
                alert("NotAvailable");
                $("#errorMessage").val("Enter a valid Quantity");
            }
            else {
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                window.location.href = url + "?custEmail=xyz@rrr.org";
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

}

The form and the AJAX call is like below

When the `result.status` returned from the controller action is  `"NotAvailable"` I am creating error message like `$("#errorMessage").val("Enter a valid Quantity");` and using this at the top of my field

```
        <input type="text" class="text-danger float-right" style="border:none;font-size: smaller" id="@("errorMessage")" readonly />
```

When try to test the validation failure scenario after I click on the button below is what I am seeing

[image]

How can I comeback to the same screen and show the error `Enter a valid Quantity` on the field

Comment: Could you please have a look the solution, I hope it would resolve accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need following modifications:

Set your button type like this :  `<button id="button" type="button">Update</button>` instead of `<button id="button">Click Me</button>`

> ***Note:*** By defualt button type is submit so it always post additional form `POST` Request so that you are redirecting to that
> page.

***Output:***

[image]

***Update:*** Though I think your `errorMessage` tag seems alright but I usually use javascript or Jquery tag slide differently as below are the full code for your reference. Feel free to customize as per your requirement.

***`HTML:`***

```
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="text-danger float-right" style="border:none;font-size: smaller" id="errorMessage" readonly />
        <form asp-action="EditItem">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OrderQuantity" id="txt" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OrderQuantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="orderId" name="orderId" value="123456" />
            <input type="hidden" id="inventoryorderId" name="inventoryorderId" value="22222" />
            <input type="hidden" id="inventoryId" name="inventoryId" value="3333" />
            <button id="button" type="button">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

***`Javascript:`***

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var orderedQuantity = $("#txt").val();
        var orderId = $("#orderId").val();
        var inventoryorderId = $("#inventoryorderId").val();
        var inventoryId = $("#inventoryId").val();
        var data = {
            orderId: orderId,
            inventoryorderId: inventoryorderId,
            inventoryId: inventoryId,
            orderedQuantity: orderedQuantity,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "Order")',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                if (data.status === "NotAvailable") {
                    alert("NotAvailable");
                    $("#errorMessage").val("Enter a valid Quantity");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Else fired");
                      var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Order")';
                window.location.href = url;
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Alert");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Hope that would resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you but still the error message is not showing up.. Do you think I have the correct tag for showing the error?

Comment: Can you please post the tags that you are using for the example above

Comment: I have updated the full answer. Hope it would help you to implement.

Comment: Thank you it did help.. I was doing `id="@("errorMessage")" `for the error message so it wasnt showing up

Comment: It should also work, but better to use `id="errorMessage"` this pattern. Glad to assist you.

Comment: Can you please suggest any ideas for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890581/display-home-page-based-on-a-condition/69892339#69892339

Comment: Seems someone already answered. By the way, does your `Identity user` issue resolved?

Comment: Yes it resolved

Comment: I have a similar requirement where I have to show a toast on successful event, I tried and it is not working as expected. I really appreciate if you can please help me with it  , show what is that I am missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075187/adding-toast-in-the-asp-net-core-razor-page

Comment: Thank you. Well, I will have a look but may require time.

Comment: Sure.. Thank you somuch.. I apreciate it