# Display Home page based on a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.Net MVC application which returns a page called Customer as home page. But I need show an app not available page when the user tries to access the application on a holiday(holiday list is stored in a table)instead of the Customer page. In the startup I have like below

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Customers}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Now I created a new page called AppNotAvialable.cshmtl and trying to return to this page if today is stored as a holiday in the HolidayWeeks table

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString,
                                               int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
        {

            var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
            var todayDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);

            var holidaycheck = (from hc in _context.HolidayWeeks
                               where hc.HolidateDate.Date == todayDt.Date
                                select hc).Count();

            if (holidaycheck != 0)
            {
                return View("/Views/Customers/AppNotAvailable.cshtml");
            }

            else
            {
               // Show customer page
```

My concern is everytime the users tried to access the homepage the query is made to the database to check if today is holiday or not. So I wanted to check if there is any better way of checking, should I be storing the data in the session/cache so everytime they access the homepage the query is not made. Can anyone please suggests me how can I do it

Comment: IMHO create a singleton service, which can cache the upcoming holidays.

Comment: @Jeremy Lakeman Can you please give me an example of how can the singleton service be created and used..

Comment: A scoped service will need to `serviceprovider.CreateScope()` so it can obtain a context and fetch records from the database. similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `MemoryCache` service to the service collection (This service caches the data on the server):

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Then can be injected by DI using the interface `IMemoryCache`.

```
//Check if there is a cached holiday vm
if (!memoryCache.TryGetValue("HolidayModelVM", out HolidayModelVM HM))//"HolidayModelVM" is the cache key for the vm
{
    //Not present in the cache, we create a new one using the database

    HM = new HolidayModelVM
    {
        //Fetch the actual entity that contains the holiday dates
    }

    //Cache the VM
    _ = memoryCache.Set<HolidayModelVM>("HolidayModelVM", HM, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),//Expiration time, when expired, the database will be used to fetch and cache a new version of the data.
        SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(2)
    });
}

//Do your holiday check using the HolidayModelVM
foreach (DayOfWeek offDay in HM.Holidays) //Holidays is a collection of DayOfWeek enums
{
    if (DateTime.UtcNow.DayOfWeek == offDay)
    {
        return View("/Views/Customers/AppNotAvailable.cshtml");
    }
}

    return View("CustomerPage");
```

When updating the holiday data clear the VM from the cache in order for the new data to be fetched next time someone visits the page:

```
memoryCache.Remove("HolidayModelVM");
```

You can also wrap all of this in a singleton service like @jeremy-lakeman suggested, do all the caching logic there and just inject and get if its a holiday or not and return a result accordingly.

Comment: Thank you !! But can you explain where is TodayIsHoliday() defined?

Comment: @user4912134 See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your holiday has fixed days, such as Saturdays and Sundays, you can do this. Here is just a demo written without caching, you can refer to it.

Model:

```
 public static class CacheKeys
    {
        public static string Saturday => "Saturday";
        public static string Sunday => "Sunday";

    }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString,
                                               int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
        {
            
          DayOfWeek wk = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;

            if (CacheKeys.Saturday == wk.ToString()|| CacheKeys.Sunday == wk.ToString())
            {
                return View("/Views/Customers/AppNotAvailable.cshtml");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("/Views/Customers/WorkDay.cshtml");
            }

            
        }
```

Just judge the current day of the week and combine your fixed holiday time.

Of course you can store the data in the session/cache, you can refer to the documentation to add it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0