# Adding Toast in the ASP.Net Core Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently building my first ASP.Net core application with Razor pages, where I am trying to add the toast to screen on when an item is successfully added to cart which is a click event on the `Add to Cart` link. I added the logic but is not working as expected. I followed [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_toast.asp) and below is the Index.cshtml where I am trying to show toast

```
<div class="toast">
   <div class="toast-body">
    Successfully added item to the cart
   </div>
</div>
 .............
 <td>
  .....
   <a href="#" id="buyNow" data-id="@item.InventoryId">Add to Cart</a>
  ......
 </td>
 .........
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#buyNow", (function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                 var id=$(this).data("id");
                onBuyNow(id);
            }));

            function onBuyNow(id) {
               .........
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("OrderItem", "Inventories")',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result !== "")
                        {
                            //showing validation errors
                            .........
                        }
                        else {
                           // Navigates to the same page back and thats where I am trying to show toast
                            var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Inventories")';
                            window.location.href = `${url}?id=${customerId}&rmID=${@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["rmID"]}`;
                            // trying to show toast on success
                            $('.toast').toast('show');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
                };
            });
    </script>
```

No toast shows up when the item got added to cart successfully. I already have references to the bootstrap in the _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>App Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

**** EDIT***

Before adding the new references in the _Layout.cshtml, it shows the navigation and all
[image]

After adding the suggested new refreneces like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>App Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The issue is it takes off the pagination from the index page and it appears like below table and the footer
[image]

Comment: Could you please have a look on the answer so that it will point you the problem. Your code is alright but `script references` is not correct. `Toast` requires those `script` suggested by `w3schools`

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help with?

Comment: Thanks I have a little sick for the past few days and couldnt look in to this

Comment: Oh I see, Get well soon, I wish you all the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have checked your code. Seems problem on your `script library`
> references. It’s not correct. The link you have followed they shared
> the link as well which you haven't used. So the take away is, for
> `toast` it requires particular library that's why you are not getting
> it.

***`Your Sample Code:`***

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="toast">
        <div class="toast-body">
            Successfully added item to the cart
        </div>
    </div>

    <td>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="buyNow" data-id="5">Add to Cart</a>

    </td>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#buyNow").click(function (e) {
         
                var id = 5;
                onBuyNow(id);
            });
            function onBuyNow(id) {
                alert("Your Product Id is : " +id);
                $('.toast').toast('show');
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

> ***Note:*** Remember to add required script link. Additionally, for internal link make sure you have those script library locally. Other
> than `toast` will not work. You can have a look [official document here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/)

***`Self-define toast without any script:`***

```
<div id="toast" class="toast" style="position: fixed; margin-left:250px; bottom: 800px;font-weight: 400;line-height: 1.5; color: !important #212529; width: 100%; max-width: 300px;border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem;    border-radius: 0.25rem; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.85); color: #6c757d; font-size: 16px; padding: 10px; user-select: none;">
    <div class="toast-header">
        Toast Header
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
        Successfully added item to the cart
    </div>
</div>

<td>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="buyNow" data-id="5">Add to Cart</a>

</td>
```

***`Self define script:`***

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#toast").hide();
            $("#buyNow").click(function (e) {

                var id = 5;
                onBuyNow(id);
            });
            function onBuyNow(id) {
                $("#toast").show();
                $("#toast").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

> ***Remarks:*** if you want to align the `toast-box position` please modify `margin-left:250px; bottom: 800px` these property as per your
> needs. Hope it would guide you to resolve the issue and save much
> time.

Comment: I tried to add the suggested references the issue it remove the pagination I have implemented. I have updated the question if the sissue

Comment: Yes, I have also got that issue. `Bootstrap` script overriding razor project script. Though to get rid of this problem lot of script required to be fixed. But I would prefer my own toast `self-define` `css` and `JavaScript` which would be more easy and time saving.