# How to make the form file not required if the path to files already exists in the DB

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a view model set up as:

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Book Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pdf Book")]
    public IFormFile BookPdfFile { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, I am using the view model properties

```
<form asp-action="CreateEdit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.BookPath))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Uploaded Book:</label>
            <a asp-action="Download" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">@Model.Name</a>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BookPdfFile" class="control-label"></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" asp-for="BookPdfFile" accept=".pdf">
        <span asp-validation-for="BookPdfFile" class="text-danger"></span>

    </div>
</form>
```

Using this View model in the view in this way always asks for the file to be uploaded. If the file is uploaded during the create mode or if it has the file path, how to not ask to make the form file required?

The Book entity is:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]

    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Path { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookChapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
```

How could I modify my code to make the form file not required if the path already exists in the DB?

On the server side I could add the validation attribute but how would I make that work on the client side as well?

I have yet not worked on posting and saving the files to the controller on HttpPost. So, my controller is just a one-line initializing the view model.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateBook()
{
    BookViewModel bookVM = new BookViewModel();

    return View("CreateEdit", bookVM);
}
```

Comment: You could add conditional after searching in database and return the respose to clinet side. It doesnt require to add validation on your model. For instance, if you found that file is already in database than you can ignore or update, or if the file not there you can inform the client.

Comment: In addition, could you please share your controller code snippet as well?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have yet not worked on posting and saving the files to the controller on HttpPost. So, my controller is just a one-line initializing the view model.
I have uploaded the code on the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Based of your scenario, easiest way to handle it by using [`javascript and ajax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69819791/show-the-validation-error-from-the-ajax-calls-inline-on-the-field/69820616#69820616) but if you don't prefer it then you can use [`custom validation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-attributes).

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron the custom validation seems to be working for the server side only and for the javascript and ajax cal, it is while saving or trying to post to the DB. But I don't want to upload the files to using javascript or jquery. I want to use the validation only in the client side.

Comment: in your view model, you can set the property as nullable, like so; public IFormFile? BookPdfFile { get; set; }. does this help?

Comment: this will not make the file required. in the create mode too. that is not what i needed.